# Counting number of occurrences of a value across multiple worksheets and criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am new to excel and am trying to learn how I would do this. Essentially what I have are two worksheets where the first worksheet has data for companies and the effective date of a policy. The following is an example of the data.

```
Company    Effective Date
A          2016/04/01
A          2016/04/01
B          2016/04/01
B          2016/04/02
```

Then I have a second worksheet that contains data whether the policy is commissionable or not. It contains columns for the companies, if the policy is commissionable, and the last day to become commissionable. Essentially if the commissionable column says no the policy will only be commissionable if the effective date is before the last date to be commissionable. The following is an example.

```
Company    Commissionable    Last date to be commissionable
A          Yes               
A          No                3/01/2016
B          No                4/25/2016
B          No                6/20/2016
```

There are some companies in the first worksheet that aren't in the second one and those need to be researched further. My goal is to count the number of commissionable policies and non-commissionable polices. I don't know where to start with and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "My goal is to count the number of commissionable policies and non-commissionable polices" - If you're just using the second worksheet, you can just use a `COUNTIF()` formula, if I understand correctly. (In cell `D2` let's say, you could do `=COUNTIF(B:B,"Yes")` and that'll return the number of policies that are marked as "Yes" in the "Commissionable" column.

Comment: The only problem is there are policies marked as No that are still commissionable based on the date, I need to check multiple criteria.

Comment: I didn't see a column for policies.. is the are numbered the same way in worksheet 1 & 2. ?